# C# Winforms duplicate emails on smtp.Send Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have this really weird issue on my most recent app where emails are being sent twice to the same recipient.

All my other apps use the same logic and same exchange server and only send mails out once.

I'm not calling the `smtp.Send()` method twice anywhere and I'm not doing anything differently, yet I can't figure this out.

My code:

```
dtExport = await PopulateClientXData();
if (dtExport.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    await SetSuccessEmails("clientX");
    if (File.Exists(clientXFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx"))
        File.Delete(clientXFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx");

    await Task.Run(() => ExportToExcel(dtExport, clientXFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx"));
    ConstructEmails(client: "clientX");
}
else
{
    ConstructEmailsNoData();
}


dtExport = await PopulateClientYData();
if (dtExport.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    await SetSuccessEmails("clientY");
    if (File.Exists(clientYFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx"))
        File.Delete(clientYFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx");

    await Task.Run(() => ExportToExcel(dtExport, clientYFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx"));
    ConstructEmails(client: "clientY");
}
else
{
    ConstructEmailsNoData();
}
```

My `ConstructEmails()` method:

```
void ConstructEmails([Optional] string errorMessage, [Optional] string client)
{
    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(mailFrom);
        message.From = fromAddress;

        foreach (var address in mailTo.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            message.To.Add(address);
        }

        foreach (var address in mailCC.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            message.CC.Add(address);
        }

        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.AlternateViews.Add(StructureEmails(emailImageFile, false));

        switch (client)
        {
            case "clientX":
                Attachment clientXAttachment = new Attachment(clientXFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx");
                message.Attachments.Add(clientXAttachment);
                break;
            case "clientY":
                Attachment clientYAttachment = new Attachment(clientYFile + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx");
                message.Attachments.Add(clientYAttachment);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        message.Subject = mailSubject;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Send(message);

        message.Attachments.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As I'm calling my `ConstructEmails()` method only once per client, why is it sending duplicate emails?

Comment: set a breakpoint to `smtpClient.Send(message);`, you can reproduce this issue in Debug mode with Visual Studio?

Comment: Does `mailTo` or `mailCC` contain anything like `"same@person.com;same@person.com"`? Or where do these variables get set? If the variable doesn't change inbetween ClientXData and ClientYData you will send it twice to the same person..

Comment: @Fixation, I checked that before asking the question.  The email addresses are set via a config file. I stream the file and assign variables based on the value in my file. I know for a fact the email only appears in the file once.

Comment: @kennyzx, what exactly should I be looking for when putting a breakpoint on `smtpClient.Send(message)`? All the properties looks normal